# Jquery undefined condition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have set a `validation` for undefined here below in my javascript code. Even if the value is `undefined` it is going inside the *if* condition

```
if (VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES != 'undefined' || VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES != "") {
    VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES = lstPanaromicImages.join();
}
```

**update**

Updated code

```
var PANAROMIC_120 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_120 != "" && PANAROMIC_120 != undefined)
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_120);

var PANAROMIC_150 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic150')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_150 != "" && PANAROMIC_150 != undefined)
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_150);

var PANAROMIC_180 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic180')).data('imagename');

if (PANAROMIC_180 != "" && PANAROMIC_180 != undefined)
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_180);

var PANAROMIC_210 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic210')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_210 != "" && PANAROMIC_210 != undefined)
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_210);

var PANAROMIC_240 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic240')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_240 != "" && PANAROMIC_240 != undefined)
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_240);

if (VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES != undefined || VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES != "") {
    VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES = lstPanaromicImages.join();
}
```

Comment: You are using `||`. I think you want to use `&&`

Comment: it's because you're using or in the if, it's because the second condtion is true, so it goes into the if statement, use `&&` instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used an `OR` operator. This means that if the `VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES` value is `undefined`, it is still different from `""`, that's why the `if` statement is true.

Just replace the `OR` operator by an `AND`:

```
if (VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES !== undefined && VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES !== "") {
    VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES = lstPanaromicImages.join();
}
```

Note that I removed the single quotes around the `undefined` keyword.

Comment: it is still going inside undefined

Comment: @VVVV Answer updated, I didnt see that you used single quotes around the `undefined` keyword.

Comment: which one is the most trustable validation to use ? any please post specific reason for that

Comment: `isNaN` checks that a value is not a number, this is clearly not what you are asking about. My code makes sure that the value is not undefined AND not an empty string.

Comment: Its answer is correct to, but I don't see the interest of using `typeof` when you can directly check the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isNaN` function in javascript.

```
if (!isNaN(VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES)) {
    VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES = lstPanaromicImages.join();
}
```

Comment: did you try this? @VVVV

Comment: superb..! its working. but y the other answer didn't worked. ?

Comment: This is not what `isNaN` is used for... See documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: yes i will accept but why `isNan` here works but not the simple `undefined` ?

Comment: I am not sure about why `!== undefined` is not working for you @VVVV

Comment: @VVVV check my updated answer. `isNaN` is not the good solution for your problem.

Comment: i did not see properly that you have mentioned in the double quotes..as i commented i thought `!== undefined ` itself is not working

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `"use strict"` in your document then you can use the following way to check:

```
if (typeof PANAROMIC_120 != "undefined" && PANAROMIC_120 != "")
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_120);
```

Note that I am using quotes over undefined when I have added `typeof`

Answer (score 0):

Check undefined condition like as follows

```
var PANAROMIC_120 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic120')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_120 != "" && typeof(PANAROMIC_120) != "undefined")
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_120);

var PANAROMIC_150 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic150')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_150 != "" && typeof(PANAROMIC_150) != "undefined")
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_150);

var PANAROMIC_180 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic180')).data('imagename');

if (PANAROMIC_180 != "" && typeof(PANAROMIC_180) != "undefined")
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_180);

var PANAROMIC_210 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic210')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_210 != "" && typeof(PANAROMIC_210) != "undefined")
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_210);

var PANAROMIC_240 = $(document.getElementById('ImgPanaromic240')).data('imagename');
if (PANAROMIC_240 != "" && typeof(PANAROMIC_240) != "undefined")
    lstPanaromicImages.push(PANAROMIC_240);

if (typeof(VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES) != "undefined" || VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES != "") {
    VSATSaving.PANORAMIC_IMAGES = lstPanaromicImages.join();
}
```